# VBScript MID function - Invalid procedure call or argument - Code 800A0005

Tags: group-policy, vbscript, logon-scripts

I've created a VBScript that aims to change folder share names on a server. This is currently running as a logon script for my test users.

I've defined this function:

```
Private Function intChangeShareName()
   Dim intPoz1, intPoz2, intIndex
   Dim strPom

   intChangeShareName = CONST_NO_CHANGE

   strActions = strActions & strOldNameShare & vbcrlf
  strPom = Trim(strOldNameShare)
  If Left(strPom, 2) <> "\\" then Exit Function

   intPoz1 = inStr(3, strPom, "\")
   intPoz2 = inStr(3, strPom, ".")
   If intPoz2 > 0 Then
      strSrvName = Mid(strPom, 3, intPoz2 - 3)
      strDomName = Mid(strPom, intPoz2 + 1, intPoz1 - intPoz2 - 1)
   Else
     strSrvName = Mid(strPom, 3, intPoz1 - 3)
      strDomName = ""
   End If

   intIndex = 0
  Do while intIndex <= UBound(arrOldSrv)
     If UCase(strSrvName) = UCase(arrOldSrv(intIndex)) Then
        If strDomName = "" Then
           strNewNameSrv = arrNewSrv(intIndex)
           strNewNameDom = ""
        intChangeShareName = CONST_CHANGE
         End If

        If UCase(strDomName) = UCase(arrOldDom(intIndex)) Then
           strNewNameSrv = arrNewSrv(intIndex)
           strNewNameDom = "." & arrNewDom(intIndex)
        intChangeShareName = CONST_CHANGE
         End If
      End If
      intIndex = intIndex + 1
   Loop

   If intChangeShareName = CONST_CHANGE Then
      strNewNameShare = "\\" & strNewNameSrv & strNewNameDom & Mid(strPom, intPoz1)
      strActions = strActions & "*  " & strNewNameShare & vbcrlf
      blRequireLogoff = True
'       Wscript.Echo "a " & strNewNameShare
   End If

End Function
```

However every time I log in I get the following error: *VBScript runtime error - Invalid procedure call or argument: 'Mid' - Code 800A0005*

I don't see anything wrong with my Mid function, can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All occurrences of [`MID` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3(v=vs.84).aspx) in your code follow syntax pattern `Mid(string, start[, length])` properly:

> Arguments
>
> - `string` String expression from which characters are returned. If string contains `Null`, `Null` is returned.
> - `start` Character position in string at which the part to be taken begins. If start is greater than the number of characters in string,
>     Mid returns a zero-length string (`""`).
> - `length` Number of characters to return. If omitted or if there are fewer than length characters in the text (including the character at
>     start), all characters from the `start` position to the end of the
>     string are returned.

Excerpted from the original code snippet, variables renamed merely for clearness:

```
iPosBackSlash = inStr(3, strPom, "\")
iPosDot       = inStr(3, strPom, ".")
If iPosDot > 0 Then
   strSrvName = Mid(strPom,           3, iPosDot - 3)
   strDomName = Mid(strPom, iPosDot + 1, iPosBackSlash - iPosDot - 1)
Else
   strSrvName = Mid(strPom,           3, iPosBackSlash - 3)
   strDomName = ""
End If
''' and thereinafter '''
strNewNameShare = "\\" & strNewNameSrv & strNewNameDom & Mid(strPom, iPosBackSlash)
```

On the other side, `MID` function would fail raising  terminating error `Invalid procedure call or argument: 'Mid' - Code 800A0005` if `start` or `length` are out of range.

Let's consider some valid *UNC* paths as possible values of `strPom` variable:

- `\\server\root`, `\\server\root\sub`, `\\server.domain\root`, `\\server.domain\root\sub`: the original function would not fail,
- but for instance `\\server\root\sub.folder` raises error in question as specified `length` i.e. `iPosBackSlash - iPosDot - 1` results to a negative number.

`If (iPosDot > 0) and (iPosDot < iPosBackSlash) Then` **should resolve the latter issue** although someone *could* find a valid *UNC* path such that `iPosDot - 3` or `iPosBackSlash - 3` would lead to the error?

**Answer**, returned to original variable names, use next **improved** `If` command:

```
If intPoz2 > 0 and (intPoz2 < intPoz1) Then
    ''' etc '''
```